# Count down multiple things at the same time in java

Tags: java, loops, minecraft

I have a project I have been working on for 2 days and so far it has been easy to work with, until I came to a roadblock where I was not able to figure out how to run multiple things at once. What I am working with is an automatic broadcast messenger for minecraft.

What I want to do with my project is when a player executes a command, it adds it to a countdown and keeps looping through it over and over again, except I want multiple thing added to it and looping through it over and over again. Basically what I have set up is when a player creates a broadcast it asks them for a few arguments, one of them is the time in minutes. When the player creates the broadcast it does not automatically start broadcasting the message, instead another command when executed starts counting down.

Different timings are set for each broadcast making it difficult for me to know how to actually make multiple broadcasts count down at the same time.

Here is the method I am working with:

```java
public static void startBroadcast(Player player, String broadcast_name) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement getTimer = plugin.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + plugin.table + " WHERE broadcast_name=?");
            getTimer.setString(1, broadcast_name);
            ResultSet results = getTimer.executeQuery();
            results.next();

            int sqlNumber = results.getInt("timer");
            int sqlNumberToSeconds = sqlNumber*60;

        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas or solutions please? thanks!

Comment: why not create only 1 countdown timer and start it when all the things which needs to be done are ready and then execute the timer.
Also, it is going to be very easy, if you type down pseudo code for what you want to do.

Comment: I would but i have no idea how to structure it or anything.

Comment: pseudo code is the steps or flow of your process, the stuff you want to do in order to reach your goal.
For single timer, i suggest Using interface. 
check this link https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp